# Crystal reports 11: how do you debug a crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports

When I'm creating a crystal report and when I add fields and fields to a database, the report outputs a completely blank report for the invoice I am creating.  How do you debug a crystal report?

Do you setup markers or flags to output? Is there an error log somewhere which describes which field the report is having an issue with etcs?

Answer (score 1):

Your 'no records' empty report can be caused by some inexpected 'default' links between tables that CR would add each time you modify the list of tables and views needed for the report. There is this 'intelligent linking' option that can even automatically create some recursive links. Be carefull while looking at these in the relations screen, as they might not be viewable 'at once'. Another situation leading to 'empty' reports is when tables are linked with an inner join instead of an outer join, or when outer joins should be switched between left and right.

If you cannot find which relation(s) is causing your report to be empty (sometimes it is not so obvious), I advise you to make some trial & errors test by adding/removing tables or modifying your links.

Answer (score 0):

You should get an error if there is an issue with the report. I'm guessing there is some logic in a join or display formula that is blanking the report. Can you verify the datasource is correct?

You can catch more errors if you handle the CrystalReportViewer error event (are you using .net?). I don't have much experience with the VS built-in designer. I use CR XIr2 standalone designer, which makes it much much easier to build reports.